# How can a child of GridView at certain position be retrieved regardless of which children are visible?

Tags: android, gridview

Suppose a GridView has the following children:

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
```

When all of them are visible, getChildAt(5) returns child 5.  If the first row is not visible, I believe that getChildAt(5) returns child 8.

Is my understanding correct?  If so, how can I always get a child of GridView with a specified index?

The following code is how I want to update a child at position iPosition with a bitmap bm:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
View vGrid = gridview.getChildAt(iPosition);

ImageView iv = (ImageView) vGrid.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

The getView of the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vGrid;

    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

        vGrid = new View(activity);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vGrid = li.inflate(R.layout.devicetile, parent, false);

    } else {
        vGrid = convertView;
    }

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) vGrid.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageBitmap(null);

    return vGrid;
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve ? Grid view wont be creating exactly the number of children based on the adapter count it will simple create some amount of views and simple reuse it

Comment: I want to update the children of a GridView based on its position in code outside the adapter.

Comment: You can change the data of the adapter and simple call adapter.validateDataSetChangesd() function, so that when the view comes to the visible area it will automatically updated.

Comment: I am wondering if that has any performance issue.  Suppose a GridView has 300 children, and 200 are visible. The children are updated one at a time with an interval of 1 second. Does that approach refresh the entire screen every time a child is updated?

Comment: Post your code this is how it works, if you don have the view in the Visible Rect u don have to call that method, when gridView calls getview method for that ite for the next time it will automatically will get updated

Comment: I added code excerpt per your suggestion.  There are over 1000 lines of code between the activity and the adapter.

Comment: Hey dude at least post your adapter code and just wanna see how the getView method works ?

Comment: I added the code per your request. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: why you are not setting any images for your view ? from where you are getting bitmap for your images ?

Comment: The images are dynamic, so they are set outside the adapter.

Comment: Dynamic in the sense ? when they getting created ? form where they getting created, it will be either from a remote url or a local file right ?

Comment: So simply create an ArrayList and set all the source of the images available to that array list and keep this array list inside your Adapter, set the image source from that

Comment: @Rajesh, thank you for all the tips and insight of GridView.  I have to say our discussion is beneficial to me, but it is getting beyond my original intended scope. I just wanted to find a way to get an element of a GridView at certain position. I may have other usage for this.  For this particular case, I have solved it by assigning each child an id that equals its position number (e.g. child 5 has an id = 5), then I retrieve the child with its id when updating the image.  It appears to be working fine.  Your method sounds good, but it may require changing the current code a lot.